Weighted Fusion of VAE Gaussian Distributions
Say you have 4 stacked output vectors of 4 different VAEs: $B \times 512 \times 4$
These $512$ elements correspond to $256 \ \mu$ &  $256 \ \ln\sigma^2$ (log-variances) of four multi-variate normal distributions that depend on one another.
My goal is to combine these four into a single multi-variate normal distribution, defined as $\mu^*$ & $\ln\sigma^{2*}$ both of size $B \times 512$ using a weighted fusion approach. There are two ideas I am considering...

1. Simply summing Gaussians
Sum of means: $\mu^*=\sum w_i * \mu_i$
Log-sum-exp trick on the log-vars: $\ln\sigma^{2*}=a + \ln ( \sum w_i * e^{\text{logvar}_i - a})$
Where

$w_i$ is a learned attention weight based on the VAEs output where $\sum w_i = 1$
$a = \max (\text{logvars})$

Implemented in PyTorch:
# Weighted mean fusion
fused_mean = torch.sum(weights * means, dim=-1)

# Weighted log-sum-exp fusion for logvars
max_logvar = torch.max(logvars, dim=-1, keepdim=True)[0] # tuple output (discard index)
weighted_var = weights * torch.exp(logvars - max_logvar)
sum_weighted_var = torch.sum(weighted_var, dim=-1, keepdim=True)
fused_logvar = max_logvar + torch.log(sum_weighted_var + eps)

return fused_mean, fused_logvar.squeeze(dim=-1)

2. Mixture model approach
This one is kind of similar but more complex and I gathered it accounts for dependencies - but I'm not a statistician!
Sum of means (same as previous approach): $\mu^*=\sum w_i * \mu_i$
Log-vars: $\ln\sigma^{2*}=a + \ln ([\sum w_i * (e^{\text{logvar}_i - a} + \mu_i^2)] - \mu^{*^{2}})$
Implemented in PyTorch:
# Weighted mean fusion
fused_mean = torch.sum(weights * means, dim=-1, keepdim=True) # (batch_size, latent_dim, 1)

# Weighted mixture variance with cross-terms
max_logvar = torch.max(logvars, dim=-1, keepdim=True)[0] # (batch_size, latent_dim, 1)
_vars = torch.exp(logvars - max_logvar) # (batch_size, latent_dim, n_views)
fused_var = torch.sum(weights * (_vars + means**2), dim=-1, keepdim=True) - fused_mean**2
fused_logvar = max_logvar + torch.log(fused_var + eps)

return fused_mean.squeeze(dim=-1), fused_logvar.squeeze(dim=-1)


My questions are:

What is the statistical significance of either approach and when should one be preferred over the other?
Are my formulas / operations correctly implemented?

For more context you can visit this repo where I'm putting this together. In a nutshell $x$ is a molecule that is represented as a string, image, graph and fingerprint, each encoded using a separate VAE and combined into a single multi-variate normal used for sampling & computing the KL-divergence. To end-goal is really to simplify and stabilize training by reducing the number of (KL) loss terms.

What is your question? Please [edit] to clarify.

why do you need 4 of them? at the end you will still model a single gaussian distribution by summing them

I've made an edit. I basically want to know if what I wrote out is correct and makes sense from a statistics perspective.
Yes, the goal is to have only 1 Gaussian distribution, raher than 4 seperate ones to make the loss-term less complex (only 1 KL rather than 4). From a biological perspective it makes sense to have 1 distribution describing the input rather than 4 seperate ones.
